# How to get private key based on Keystore UTC file?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, metamask, go-ethereum, web3py

I'm running ethereum private node on my system, I forgot my account password.

Anyone, please help me to get a private key based on the Keystore UTC file.

Answer (score 1):

The account password is used to encrypt the keystore file data, so basically without the password, you will not be able to recover your account even if you have access to the keystore file.

https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/interface/managing-your-accounts

> If you lose the password you use to encrypt your account, you will not be able to access that account. Repeat: It is NOT possible to access your account without a password and there is no forgot my password option here. Do not forget it.

Comment: link is not working sir, update your link

Answer (score 0):

one of the way is to decode it via web3js.

let the json file is node/keystore/UTCaccount.json. then code to get private key is

```
const web3=require('web3')
var Accounts = require('web3-eth-accounts');
var accounts = new Accounts('ws://localhost:8546');

// let afo = web3.eth.accounts.decrypt(JSON, password);
/*
   input: @json @password
   output: {
          address: '0xB5a317aAD9AaAC19532df0d00891B2A0D11FF766',
          privateKey: '0xbd5649c47a00818c3e0ea7d085232192dc8f31981f02e2e932447ba042b50864',
        }
*/ 

const decode = (json,pass) =>{
    let output = accounts.decrypt(json,pass);
    return output;
}

const pass="aakash"

// node/keystore/<wallet json>
const json={
    "address": "b5a317aad9aaac19532df0d00891b2a0d11ff766",
    "crypto": {
        "cipher": "aes-128-ctr",
        "ciphertext": "333a3e7d0a436ee5f8d5b576e56904d05de33f143ff005ce47537b45ee932dc4",
        "cipherparams": {
            "iv": "7e6d239558bb4385480d7c09675aed14"
        },
        "kdf": "scrypt",
        "kdfparams": {
            "dklen": 32,
            "n": 262144,
            "p": 1,
            "r": 8,
            "salt": "56ce29365b13bdce82aa068da46186c216e4c6de4a85b097cd5c47a71e0a159f"
        },
        "mac": "1eebc09f190f5f591028443b3ce956a18e479027ee2d4f0f6b2c1bde7f27be2c"
    },
    "id": "e6e30b97-73ce-4a2b-a1d5-fb6be5df3e23",
    "version": 3
}

console.log(decode(json,pass))
```